# How can I get amount of rows in Excel file via xlwt

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt

How can I get amount of rows in Excel file via xlwt? Is it unable and I should open this file for read via xlrd just for get this info?

Comment: Do you mean rows that you have already written or rows of an existing file?  The first you should keep track of yourself. The latter is impossible with xlwt.

Comment: Also remember you cannot edit an existing file with xlwt.  xlwt can only create new files.  You must copy the existing file with [xlutils.copy](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/copy.html) or xlrd and xlwt in tandem to create a modified copy of the file and overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with xlwt only. Use xlrd ([Sheet.nrows](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.nrows-attribute)) or xlutils. Example from [xlutils docs](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/api.html#xlutils.margins.number_of_good_rows):

```
>>> from xlutils.tests.fixtures import make_sheet
>>> sheet = make_sheet((
...           ('X',' ',' ',' ',' '),
...           (' ',' ',' ','X',' '),
...           (' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
...           ('X',' ',' ',' ',' '),
...           (' ',' ','X',' ',' '),
...           (' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
...           ))
>>> from xlutils.margins import number_of_good_rows
>>> number_of_good_rows(sheet)
5
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this topic is a bit old but it's the first google result when lookink for this issue. I'm using python 3.6 with xlwt 1.2.0 and to get worksheet length I use this:

```
len(ws._Worksheet__rows) #care the simple then double underscore
```

Comment: with empty lines this returns the wrong number